# Userform to enter information and when recalled will show what was entered previously

Tags: excel, vba, userform

New with VBA so code may be a little larger than needed (ie could have been made objects, etc.). I Need to be able to enter information with userform and later if a revision is needed, it recalls the same userform and has the data that was previously entered in the textBoxes/listBoxes.

The issue that I am having is that I am having a "Run-time error '380' Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value".

If I take out the 'Vice Versa for Revisions' section it enters just fine, but then when recalling the userform it's blank again.

Any advice on how to fix or even clean up code would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub E_EnterInformation_Click()

'----------------------------------------------------
'Check Validation of Completed form
'----------------------------------------------------
If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Request By' on form"
        Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'On Site Contact' on form"
        Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'On Site Phone Number' on form"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value) = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_EventName.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Event Name' on form"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Location Number' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Off Site Delivery?' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Request Status' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Delivery Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Delivery Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show Start Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show Start Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show End Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_SETime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_SETime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Show End Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.Value) = "" Then
  Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Pickup Date' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.ListIndex) = -1 Then
  Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please fill in 'Pickup Time' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

'Hide or show offsite and order number boxes

If Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.Value = "Yes" Then
    EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = True
    EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = True
    Else
    EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = False
    EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.Visible = False
    End If

If Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.Value = "Yes" And Me.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.Value = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OffSiteAdd.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Enter Off Site Location Name and Address' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.Value <> "New" Then
    EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OrderNum.Visible = True
    EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OrderNum.Visible = True
    Else
    EquipmentRequest.LabelE_OrderNum.Visible = False
    EquipmentRequest.TextBoxE_OrderNum.Visible = False
    End If

If Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.Value <> "New" And Me.TextBoxE_OrderNum.Value = "" Then
    Me.TextBoxE_OrderNum.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please fill in 'Enter Order/Job #' on form"
  Exit Sub
End If


'--------------------------------------------
'Enter Data in Form
'--------------------------------------------

Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C6") = Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.Value       'Name of Requester
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C7") = Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.Value   'Name of Contact
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C8") = Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.Value    'Phone Number format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("F10") = Me.TextBoxE_Comments.Value       'Comments (not required)

Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I6") = Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value       'Name of Event
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I7") = Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.Value 'Location Number
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I8") = Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.Value 'Yes or No Selection
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I9") = Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.Value   'New or revision or cancel selection

Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C9") = Me.TextBoxE_PWDate.Value          'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D9") = Me.ListBoxE_PWTime.Value          'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C10") = Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.Value    'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D10") = Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.Value    'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C11") = Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.Value         'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D11") = Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.Value         'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C12") = Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.Value         'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D12") = Me.ListBoxE_SETime.Value         'Time Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C13") = Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.Value     'Short Date Format
Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D13") = Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.Value     'Time Format

'-----------------------------------------
'Vice Versa for Revisions
'-----------------------------------------

If Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value <> "" Then

Me.TextBoxE_RequestBy.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C6")
Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteContact.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C7")
Me.TextBoxE_OnSiteNumber.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C8")
Me.TextBoxE_Comments.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("F10")

Me.TextBoxE_EventName.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I6")
Me.ComboBoxE_LocationNumber.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I7")
Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I8")
Me.ListBoxE_RequestStatus.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I9")

Me.TextBoxE_PWDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C9")
Me.ListBoxE_PWTime.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D9")
Me.TextBoxE_DeliverDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C10")
Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D10")
Me.TextBoxE_SSDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C11")
Me.ListBoxE_SSTime.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D11")
Me.TextBoxE_SEDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C12")
Me.ListBoxE_SETime.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D12")
Me.TextBoxE_PickupDate.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("C13")
Me.ListBoxE_PickupTime.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D13")

End If

'------------------------------------------------------
'Message box when data has been correctly added
'------------------------------------------------------
'MsgBox "Show Information Added to Form", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Show Information Added to Form"

Unload Me

Call ESaveBook

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to know at which line you are getting the error... the code is quite large indeed. Though I would assume those `ListBox...Value` is causing you a problem. Try something like this `Me.ListBoxE_PWTime.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D9")`

Comment: I tried this solution and at the first listbox Me.ListBoxE_OffSiteDelivery.AddItem = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("I8") , 'AdItem was highlighted with a compile error saying expected function.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has to do with the way you are attempting to assign values with your list boxes. It looks like you have a few items in your list boxes and you want to select or highlight the one that the user picked last. If that's the case you can't do it like this:

```
Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D10")
```

It will either throw an error or display nothing in the list box. The reason why is because to select or highlight an item in a list box (show what the user previously selected) you have to pass in an integer value for the index:

```
Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.Selected(2) = True
```

Which would select/highlight the 3rd item in the list box. So to show in the list box what the user previously selected or entered you would need to use a workaround, like a *case statement*, then pass in the integer value that corresponds to the text.

If you only want to show the text from the cell containing the previous selection (D10 in this case) you can add it as an item in the list box:

```
Me.ListBoxE_DeliverTime.AddItem (Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("D10").Value2)
```

My suggestion however is to avoid list boxes entirely. The names of your list boxes suggest that you're abstracting and displaying a single value at a time (previously entered date, previously entered time); if that's the case you're better off using a text box or a label for each value.

As a side note it's good practice to be explicit with vba. When you enter code like this:

```
Me.TextBoxE_Comments.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("F10")
```

It may work (this time), but if you're purely interested in abstracting the value from the cell then your code will be most efficient by adding .Value2 to the end:

```
Me.TextBoxE_Comments.Value = Sheets("Equipment Request").Range("F10").Value2
```

.Value2 abstracts *value* from the target with no formatting.